# Unity post processing layer does not appear

Tags: unity-game-engine, post-processing

I am very new to unity and I am trying to add post processing to a scene. I copied a tutorial, however when I added the post processing layer to my camera and went to change the layer to post processing, there was no post processing layer.
There should be a layer called post processing here, unless I did something wrong:

[image]

It doesn't seem like anyone else has had this problem but that could be because it's an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend restarting the project once, assuming you've correctly imported Post Processing from the Package Manager (To make sure the layer names load up correctly).

Also, the Layer name can be created by you, and assigned to desired GameObjects. So, the name "PostProcessing" as a layer doesn't really matter. you can just add in the layer name, if it doesn't appear, and continue as it was in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to Default if it doesn't appear (Unity will warn you, though).

PostProcessing layer is usually generated when you imported the package. If it's not there, try to use a project template that has PostProcessing in it while creating a new project.